# Laravel query order by abs numerical value does not work

Tags: mysql, laravel

I have to get the first absolute values out of a float column which can have both positive and negative values.
Unfortunately, my query is not working as expected:

```
$matches = $matches->where('pick_score', '<>', '0');
$matches = $matches->orderByRaw('ABS(pick_score)', 'DESC');
```

The result of the query is completely wrong because orderByRaw sees my column as a String, instead of a float, and the values are sorted as if they are alphabetically.
What can I use in order to order them and also use abs?

Comment: What's the type of column `pick_score`?

Comment: column pick_score is float

Comment: Do you know if the query that generates is what you're intending? Does it work or fail independently of Laravel?

Comment: the query is right, this is it in mysql: select *  from matches m where pick_score<>0  order by ABS(pick_score) DESC

Comment: I read on the internet that "orderByRaw" orders the column as if it would have String values, no matter that its type is float, double or anything unrelated to Strings...so maybe I should replace it with sth else in order to execute right the abs and the order...

Comment: That doesn't make any sense. If the query is being generated with literal `ORDER BY ABS(...) DESC` in it then no conversion should take place. Are you sure you're not sorting application-side for some reason? If the query is, for some reason, `ORDER BY 'ABS(...)' DESC` then the sort didn't generate correctly and they're all being "sorted" by a static string.